# How to draw path with relative coordinates in amcharts map?

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts, svg-animate

I want to animate drawing line on map as like this

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.line-board').addClass("absolut")
    }, 200);
});
```

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21q28158/)**

I have line with absolute coordinates and animation fails.
May be is there way to convert absolute coordinates into relative in js or other way to animate drawing line like I want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to be with the order you put the data in the `dataProvider` JSon.